# Batch fill pdf form from Excel, csv, tsv

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, batch, adobe-acrobat

I know that I can fill the pdf form, from tsv by using `More form options > Import data` in acrobat pro. But this fills out only one form with only one row of information. I want to batch fill and save the pdf form from all rows of tsv at once. How can I automate this? I also know that it can be done in word by using mail merge feature. But I have different type of pdf forms which is daunting to change to word format every time I stumble upon new pdf form. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe my open source tool [BulkPDF](http://bulkpdf.de/en) could do what you want.

#### What is BulkPDF?

> BulkPDF is a free and easy to use freeware software (Open Source), which allows to automatically fill an existing PDF form with different values. Only a spreadsheet (Microsoft Excel 2007/2010/2013, LibreOffice or OpenOffice Calc) with the desired values is required.

#### How does it work?

> BulkPDF automatically recognizes the values in the selected table. Then the column names must be manually assigned to the form fields. After the fill progress have started, BulkPDF will go through line by line and write the cell value into the form.

#### Functions

- Supports text fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, combo boxes, and list boxes
- Individual configuration for each form field
- Filename freely configurable with automatic value
- Setable write protection for individual form fields as well as for the entire document
- Save and load the configuration
- Configuration manually adjustable (XML)
- Relative paths in the configuration file possible
- Command line tool available
- Compatible with Acroform and XFA

[image]

[image]

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I believe InDesign has a feature to mail merge spreadsheets and PDF forms. There are also paid 3rd party plugins and VBA scripts to do a mail merge from inside Acrobat itself.

Coding a solution is not too difficult - in the past I have used Python to code quick, custom solutions. In the code, you'll need to read each row of the spreadsheet and create an FDF file for the pdf form. Once you have the FDF, you can use PDFTK to merge the original PDF form and the FDF file and create a filled-in version of the PDF form.

If coding isn't your thing, I built a free site where you can mail merge a spreadsheet and a pdf form at [pdfzero.com](https://www.pdfzeroc.com). You can upload a pdf form and a spreadsheet, click on the pdf fields you want to fill in, and select the column you want to use for that field. You can also specify a filename using column data to keep things organized. Once the files are processed, it will return a zip file with all of the merged PDFs.

**DISCLAIMER - I wrote Pdfzero**

Comment: This is a great free tool. I was searching for exactly this, and there were so many click-bait traps to just get a simple no-code task done. Really appreciate your work on this in a pinch. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use regularly [PDF Mail Merger](https://pdfmailmerger.com) for all types of PDF forms that we have to send in bulk. We find it very easy to use.

### Usage:

You will be guided through 4 steps:

1. Upload PDF file
2. Upload Excel file
3. In the Editor you can drag'n'drop placeholders onto the PDF
4. Click to start the PDF generation

### Advantages:

- Works with any kind of PDF file (doesn't require fillable form fields)
- Many spreadsheet formats supported (Microsoft Excel, Open Office Spreadsheet, CSV, TXT etc.)
- New PDF Form templates are set up very quickly
- PDF Form templates can be reused with one click
- No programming knowledge is required

### Disadvantages:

- The free plan only covers the generation of 100 documents

### Screenshots:

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDJn.png)

[Upload PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOyHs.png)

[Editor for drag'n'drop placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dErus.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly get the job done with a simple drag and drop, I think [Bulk PDF](https://bulk-pdf.com) is the right thing for you. (disclaimer: I created this beauty)

- No Signup
- We will delete your data right away
- Custom naming of the generated pdf files
- Download your files as a merged pdf or one per data entry

[image]